# Can I use eBPF to replace a kernel function?

Tags: kernel, hook, ebpf

Can I use eBPF to reimplement a kernel function and jump to the reimplemented function when the original function is called, skipping the original function altogether?

For example, there is a kernel function A:

```
void A() 
{
    xxx;
}
```

Can I use eBPF to reimplement function A as ebpf_A, so that when function A is called, ebpf_A is executed instead of A? So I can do some other things in ebpf_A.

If I can, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this, it isn't possible to replace arbitrary functions. It is however possible to replace certain function pointers in structures, these have to be pre-designated to allow this.

To allow this a new program type was introduced called BPF_PROG_TYPE_STRUCT_OPS. The [original patch](https://lwn.net/Articles/809092/) set focused on allowing you to replace the default TCP Congestion Control. I believe that so far that is the only actual use-case for which this is enabled.